# getting started with Rails 3 forum engine Forem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This (https://github.com/radar/forem) is the code for the Rails 3 forum engine, but there's also a sample app ( http://forem.heroku.com/ )

I've got the engine installed (and devise authentication! installed) but am having trouble going farther. I wonder, is there code for the sample app  ( http://forem.heroku.com/ ) that I can look at to learn from?

Right now, when I go to localhost:3000/forums, I get what you see in the attached image. I'm not 100% sure if that's what I'm supposed to see (i.e. I have to build out the models for topics, categories etc and create an admin user? )  or if there's supposed to be a forum ready-to-go out of the box.

If I could see the sample code for http://forem.heroku.com/ it would really help me learn (which is my primary objective...I'm a hobbyist )

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote Forem. I think I can answer this question.

The sample code lives at http://github.com/radar/forem.heroku.com. This example app contains a theme, installed exactly (or at least, I think exactly) the way that it suggests to install one in the README. The theme is the "twist" theme.

The system (as of this writing) doesn't come with a forum pre-built, but it's on [the todo list](https://github.com/radar/forem/issues/91). So you'll just have to create one yourself.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, after you gave me the code link via Twitter, I was going to answer the question myself, but I have to wait a certain period of time before I can answer my own questions...